# Javascript Maze Runner on Codewars error

Tags: javascript, maps, codewarrior

I've working my way through codewars, and I've come across mazerunner (https://www.codewars.com/kata/maze-runner/train/javascript) I've been stumped for about 2 days!

```
function mazeRunner(maze, directions) {

//find start value  

var x = 0; //x position of the start point
var y = 0; //y position of the start point

for (var j = 0 ; j < maze.length ; j++){
if (maze[j].indexOf(2) != -1){
  x = j;
  y = maze[j].indexOf(2)
}
      } // end of starting position forloop

console.log(x + ', ' + y)


  for (var turn = 0 ; turn < directions.length ; turn++){


if (directions[turn] == "N"){
 x -= 1;
}
if (directions[turn] == "S"){
 x += 1;
}
if (directions[turn] == "E"){
 y += 1;
}
if (directions[turn] == "W"){
 y -= 1;
}

 if (maze[x][y] === 1){
 return 'Dead';
 }else if (maze[x][y] === 3){
 return 'Finish';
 }

if (maze[x] === undefined || maze[y] === undefined){
return 'Dead';
}

}

return 'Lost';

}
```

When I run this, it works on most of the scenarios, however on the last one I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
at mazeRunner
at /home/codewarrior/index.js:87:19
at /home/codewarrior/index.js:155:5
at Object.handleError
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm pulling my hair out over this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your solution is that after the move, you just check the value of `maze[x][y]`

In the test that fails, `maze[x]` will be at some point `undefined` (moves south for a while). I guess at that same point `y` would be `3`, hence the error `Cannot read property '3' of undefined`

To avoid that, you should move up the code where you test for undefined, before trying to access the coordinates:

```
// move this as first check
if (maze[x] === undefined || maze[y] === undefined){
  return 'Dead';
}
```

Comment: Wow! That worked a treat! Thanks! That makes sense and has worked!! I've been scratching my head for days! Thanks again!